# Is there an observer dependent temperature everywhere in spacetime?

Tags: thermodynamics, general-relativity, temperature, observers

A temperature $T=\dfrac{\hbar a}{2\pi c k_B}$ is associated to an uniformly accelerated observer. He feels this temperature all along his trajectory. The inertial observer will not assign this temperature to the corresponding points of space-time.

I wonder if for a given metric on space-time each map assign a temperature at $x$, $t$ for the observer with $x =$ constant. This is done near the horizon of black holes for static observers. Is it always possible?

Comment: Counterexample: There are two black holes and me, an observer, all at rest relative to one another. The black holes are of unequal size. The spectrum of radiation I observe is a superposition of two thermal spectra, which is not itself a thermal spectrum.

Comment: But you can read something on your thermometer. my question is about

Comment: ...what is read.

Comment: *But you can read something on your thermometer.* It's of no interest what a thermometer reads when it's not in thermal equilibrium with the stuff being measured.

Comment: in this Arxiv paper https://arxiv.org/abs/1512.06546

Comment: the author writes " even spacetime , like matter, can possess a heat density. As I will soon describe, it is possible to as
sociate a temperature and entropy density with every event in spacetime j
ust as you could have done it to a glass of water" . Jacobson also derived the einstein equation with the same argument.